# iPad и iPhone игнорируют overflow: hidden у html. Как исправить?

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такая верстка. Проблема в том, что iPad и iPhone игнорируют `overflow: hidden;` у html. Из за чего это происходит и как можно исправить?
Эта же проблема и на Android в браузере Firefox Focus.

```js
$('.js-toggle').on("click", function() {

  if ($('nav').offset().top > 0 && !$('.sub').hasClass('active')) {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: $('nav').offset().top,
      behavior: "smooth"
    })
  }

  if (!$('.sub').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.sub').addClass('active');
    $('html').addClass('no-scroll');
  } else {
    $('.sub').removeClass('active');
    $('html').removeClass('no-scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.x-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: #eaeaea;
  height: 200px;
}

.nav {
  background: lightcoral;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative
}

.content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
}

.paragraph {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.sub {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightcoral;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  display: none;
}

.sub li {
  padding: 15px;
}

.sub.active {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x-layout">
  <header class="header">
    header
  </header>
  <nav class="nav"><button class="js-toggle" type="button" name="toggle-menu">Click!</button>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
      <li>Item 15</li>
      <li>Item 16</li>
      <li>Item 17</li>
      <li>Item 18</li>
      <li>Item 19</li>
      <li>Item 20</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main class="content">
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в стиль `.no-scroll`:

```
.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```js
$('.js-toggle').on("click", function() {

  if ($('nav').offset().top > 0 && !$('.sub').hasClass('active')) {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: $('nav').offset().top,
      behavior: "smooth"
    })
  }

  if (!$('.sub').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.sub').addClass('active');
    $('html').addClass('no-scroll');
  } else {
    $('.sub').removeClass('active');
    $('html').removeClass('no-scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.x-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: #eaeaea;
  height: 200px;
}

.nav {
  background: lightcoral;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative
}

.content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
}

.paragraph {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.sub {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightcoral;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  display: none;
}

.sub li {
  padding: 15px;
}

.sub.active {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x-layout">
  <header class="header">
    header
  </header>
  <nav class="nav"><button class="js-toggle" type="button" name="toggle-menu">Click!</button>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
      <li>Item 15</li>
      <li>Item 16</li>
      <li>Item 17</li>
      <li>Item 18</li>
      <li>Item 19</li>
      <li>Item 20</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main class="content">
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
    <p class="paragraph">lorem</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Данный метод пробывал, но он работает не так как нужно.