# Как сделать чтобы фокус был на модальном окне и скролилось при открытии оно? А не задняя часть документа? Не через js

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: Окно]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
  "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji",
  "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  padding-bottom: 10vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  height: 7vh;
  justify-content: flex-end;

  &__menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    &-item {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-right: 2em;
      list-style: none;

      &-link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #007bff;
        background-color: transparent;

        &:hover {
          color: #0056b3;
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.container {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  width: 80%;
  padding-right: 0.396875cm;
  padding-left: 0.396875cm;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: -10vh;
  /*Минус Высота футера*/
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 33.866cm) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
}

.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
}

.modal__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-state {
  display: none;
}

.modal-state:checked + .modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-state:checked + .modal .modal__inner {
  top: 0;
}

.modal__inner {
  transition: top 0.25s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.1cm;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  height: 50%;
  resize: both;
}

.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal__close:after,
.modal__close:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.05cm;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: #ccc;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin: -0.079375cm 0 0 -0.02cm;
  top: 0;
}

.modal__close:hover:after,
.modal__close:hover:before {
  background: #aaa;
}

.modal__close:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 20.32cm) {

}

@media screen and (max-width: 24.2cm) {
  .modal__inner {
    width: auto !important;
    height: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 3cm) and (max-width: 35.6875cm) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 2.4vh;
  }
}
/*
@media screen and (min-height: 9.128125cm) and (max-height: 25.92916666667cm) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 1vw !important;
  }
}
*/
@media screen and (min-width: 35.6875cm) and (max-width: 108cm) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 2vh;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 108cm) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 2vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header id="header " class="header">
        <nav class="navbar">
          <ul class="navbar__menu">
            <li class="navbar__menu-item">
              <a class="navbar__menu-item-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar__menu-item">
              <a class="navbar__menu-item-link" href="#">Service</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar__menu-item">
              <a href="" class="navbar__menu-item-link__svg"
                ><label for="modal-1">
                  <svg
                    version="1.1"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    x="0px"
                    y="0px"
                    viewBox="0 0 14 14"
                    fill="#007bff"
                    height="2em"
                    width="2em"
                    style="enable-background:new 0 0 14 14;"
                    cursor="pointer"
                    xml:space="preserve"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M7,9L5.268,7.484l-4.952,4.245C0.496,11.896,0.739,12,1.007,12h11.986
                        c0.267,0,0.509-0.104,0.688-0.271L8.732,7.484L7,9z"
                    />
                    <path
                      d="M13.684,2.271C13.504,2.103,13.262,2,12.993,2H1.007C0.74,2,0.498,2.104,0.318,2.273L7,8
               L13.684,2.271z"
                    />
                    <polygon points="0,2.878 0,11.186 4.833,7.079" />
                    <polygon points="9.167,7.079 14,11.186 14,2.875" />
                  </svg>
                </label>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="text">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
              fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
              cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
              saepe similique soluta temporibus?
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
              fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
              cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
              saepe similique soluta temporibus?
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
              fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
              cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
              saepe similique soluta temporibus?
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
              fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
              cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
              saepe similique soluta temporibus?
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam
              fuga illo ipsum recusandae sapiente vero, voluptatum? Ad cum
              cupiditate dolor, et excepturi magnam quasi repellat reprehenderit
              saepe similique soluta temporibus?
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="modal-state" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" />
        <div class="modal">
          <label class="modal__bg" for="modal-1"></label>
          <div class="modal__inner">
            <label class="modal__close" for="modal-1"></label>
            <h2>Some Text</h2>
            <p class="modal__inner-text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum
              dolorem ducimus expedita id ipsum iste omnis ut? Beatae,
              blanditiis dicta, ea eaque fugiat in minima odit officia
              praesentium, vitae voluptas.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer" id="footer">
      <p class="footer-text">copyright 2019</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: обычно при открытии модального окна  контейнеру типа body присваивают overflow:hidden, тогда прокрутка фона пропадает

Comment: это через js надо делать?Просто открытие у меня через css

Comment: Каким образом можно открыть **модальное** окно через css? Имеется ввиду `hover`? Тогда это не совсем модальное. Но да, класс/стиль надо присваивать через js

Comment: @Grundy, как застваить работать `oveflow:hidden` на `body/html` в safari iOS?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что именно он не работает?

Comment: если есть класс  `.hidden с overflow:hidden` как его добавить при открытии модалки?

Comment: @Grundy, через `:target`, скорее всего. UPD, ага, вообще через checkbox -_-

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, не, там чекбокс скрытый есть и от его состояния показывается или нет

Comment: @Grundy, можно было бы попытаться переделать под `:target`, только вешать его на body, после `body:target {overflow: hidden;} body #name.modal {top: 0;}`, вот только как "закрыть" потом?))

Comment: @olliJes, простой реализации на CSS вряд ли получится.. Почему боитесь использовать JS\JQ?

Comment: таск через css сделать))

Comment: @Grundy, была такая проблема. Задавал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/889974/193678), ответа так и не получил.